# SD card won't mount when Xperia Neo V is connected to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd, mount

I upgraded my Ubuntu set up to 12.10 and realized that the SD card can't mount like it used to every time I connected my Neo V (running android 2.3.4). It can't be a hardware issue as it mounts successfully via a card reader. It also mounts successfully on Windows 7 too.

For some strange reason the phone charges normally when the USB cable is connected but Ubuntu just doesn't recognize the connected phone or its SD card. How do I rectify this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saw this question on **AskUbuntu**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065964

Please add your self to the support bug posted above. This is a known kernel regression in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Thanks for the bug link. Just I suspected it is a kernel issue. Hope Canonical fixes this real soon.

Answer (score -1):

Change USB connection mode to "Mass Storage Mode".